# Make angular pan google map to postition

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using the angular google map api (http://goo.gl/dtD7hk). I would like to make the map pan to the a position.

In my controller I have the following function:

```
$scope.mapHome = function(){    
  $scope.map.center.latitude = $rootScope.center.lat;    
  $scope.map.center.longitude = $rootScope.center.lng; 
};
```

But this doesn't work. How can I make google map pan? Would be really nice, if some way of animation was included. Zoom Out - pan - and zoom in to setting ($scope.map.zoom).

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try re-assigning the center object in your scope instead of the latitude/longitude properties:

```
$scope.mapHome = function(){    
    $scope.map.center = {
        latitude: $rootScope.center.lat,
        longitude: $rootScope.center.lng
    };
};
```

I implemented something similar and this worked for me.